# How to instantiate a python connection pool from cloud run with redis.StrictRedis to connect securely to google cloud Redis (Memstore)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, redis, google-cloud-run

From a cloud run service, I successfully create a connection to google cloud Redis with:

```
redis_webhooks = redis.StrictRedis(
            host=redis_webhooks_host,
            port=redis_webhooks_port,
            password=redis_webhooks_authstring,
            ssl=True,
            db=1,
            ssl_cert_reqs="required",
            ssl_ca_certs=f"/tmp/{redis_webhooks_server_ca_pem_name}",
        )
```

I am now trying to instantiate a connection pool, for better performance, I am trying to follow docs and the official google guide and Redis guide, however none of the references how to do this with authentication

I landed on this but it doesnt work, there are unexpected keywords "ssl", then "ssl_cert_reqs" and so on.

```
pool = redis.ConnectionPool(
            host=redis_webhooks_host,
            port=redis_webhooks_port,
            password=redis_webhooks_authstring,
            ssl=True,
            db=1,
            ssl_cert_reqs="required",
            ssl_ca_certs=f"/tmp/{redis_webhooks_server_ca_pem_name}",
        )
redis_webhooks_client = redis.StrictRedis(connection_pool=pool)
```

I also tried splitting connection and authentication like:

```
pool = redis.ConnectionPool(
            host=redis_webhooks_host,
            port=redis_webhooks_port,
            password=redis_webhooks_authstring,
            db=1,
            max_connections=100, 
            socket_timeout=5,    
            retry_on_timeout=True
        )

redis_webhooks_client = redis.StrictRedis(
            connection_pool=pool,
            ssl=True,
            ssl_cert_reqs="required",
            ssl_ca_certs=f"/tmp/{redis_webhooks_server_ca_pem_name}"
        )
```

But here i get connection reset by the peer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Google only provides simple examples.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Behind the scenes, redis-py uses a connection pool to manage connections to a Redis server. By default, each Redis instance you create will in turn create its own connection pool. You can override this behavior and use an existing connection pool by passing an already created connection pool instance to the connection_pool argument of the Redis class. You may choose to do this in order to implement client side sharding or have finer grain control of how connections are managed.

> > > pool = redis.ConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
> > > r = redis.Redis(connection_pool=pool)

Comment: Thank you @Yoni, are you saying there is no need for me to set up my own pool, as its managed behind the scene? this snippet still doesnt cover how to instantiate the custom pool with cloud run and Redis on google cloud

Answer (score 0):

From: [*Enabling Secure Connections to Redis Enterprise Cloud in Python*](https://redis.com/blog/enabling-secure-connections-redis-enterprise-cloud-python/)

I tried their example and did not get the error you mentioned.
They have more ssl settings than you.

```
import redis
import pprint
 
try:
  r = redis.StrictRedis(
    decode_responses=True,
    host='redis-16148.c15.us-east-1-2.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com',
    port=16148,
    password='sekret',
    ssl=True, 
    ssl_keyfile='./redislabs_user_private.key', 
    ssl_certfile='./redislabs_user.crt', 
    ssl_cert_reqs='required', 
    ssl_ca_certs='./redislabs_ca.pem',
    )
 
  info = r.info()
  pprint.pprint(info)
 
except Exception as err:
  print("Error connecting to Redis: {}".format(err))
```

and I got 403 forbidden, cause I don't have an account.
I installed redis v5.0.1

Comment: thanks @xyllywyt, note that my initial code does work, to create 1 connection. I am aiming to create a connection pool, for which I cannot find any documentation, on how to make it work on cloud run, with authentication, thst is the code not working... hope it makes more sense